# rename before upload file to the random name and use the file name after that

Tags: php, image, upload, rename

i have this codes and upload images fine but in one part checking 'if file exists' dont upload.i want remove this part and set a random name to file. and use the new file name.
codes:

```
$target_dir = "pics/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer: Since, it has been marked duplicate I'm editing to post the answer here as well.

```
<?php 
if(file_exists($target_file))
{
    $fileExt = explode('.',$target_file);
    $fileActualExt = ".".strtolower(end($fileExt));
    rename($target_file,str_replace($fileActualExt,("1".$fileActualExt),$target_file));
    echo $target_file;
}
?>
```

Comment: i see this link but don't work for me. that one checking if file exist but i want to remove this command and lets upload all files. i am not professional sorry

Comment: @Harshit Damani this rename file name one time! and how can put the new name in a variable?